# How do you add a custom component in admin-on-rest that doesn't require login

Tags: admin-on-rest

How would I able to add a custom page(component) to admin-on-rest that is public? Note, I would like to use the admin component so the layout is there.

Comment: Did you read the "writing actions" documentation? All you need is written there in detail. https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Actions.html

Answer (score 0):

If your application was named `myApp`, the easiest way in my opinion is to have two folders in your react project's source directory:

```
 1. /myApp/src/public
 2. /myApp/src/private
```

In `(1)` you would have your public components, with their own router and routes mapped to paths that render components stored in your `src/public` subfolder, as you would normally do with a standard **react + react-router** application.

In `(2)` you would have the admin-on-rest file structure.

There are other ways, such as injecting custom routes to the `Admin` component and customizing your own `authClient` to ignore certain routes, but I found the above method simple and clean, and it also helps keeping stuff organized.

You can find more help here:

1. [Custom Routes](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest//Admin.html#customroutes/)
2. [Authentication Documentation](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest//Authentication.html)

I hope this helps.